# prove that the sequence converges using the definition of a limit

Tags: calculus

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers and let $(n_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ be a strictly
increasing sequence of natural numbers. Suppose that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}a_n = L$ for
some $L ∈ \Bbb{R}$.

(a) Prove, by using induction, that $n_k$ ≥ k for every $k\in\Bbb{N}$.  **- -

(b) We define a sequence $(b_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ by:
$(b_k)= a_{n_k}$ for every $k\in\Bbb{N}$.

Prove,
by using the definition of the limit and item (a), that $\displaystyle{\lim_{k \to \infty}}b_k = L$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE! I presume that you're learning about *subsequences*: this exercise proves that, if a sequence converges to some limit $L$, then every subsequence converges to that same limit. For example, $(\frac1n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$, so the subsequence $(\frac1{2n})_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$ as well.

Anyways, to guide you through the problem: it can indeed be confusing, given all the notations that are required to prove convergence. What you will need to do is change some of the notations: recall that the convergence of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to $L$ translates to
$$\forall\varepsilon>0,\;\exists k\geq0,\;\forall n\geq k,\;|a_n-L|<\varepsilon. \tag{$*$}$$
Notice that I use the notation $k$ instead of $N$. This doesn't change anything to the truth of the statement, but will (hopefully) help clarify the next steps. Fix $\varepsilon>0$, and fix $k\geq0$ as specified in $(*)$ (the previous statement). From question $a$ we deduce that
$$\forall k'\geq k,\quad n_{k'}\geq k'\geq k,$$
so in particular $n_{k'}$ satisfies the condition that $n$ satisfies in the statement $(*)$. Combining these two statements, we get
$$\forall\varepsilon>0,\;\exists k\geq0,\;\forall k'\geq k,\;n_{k'}\geq k\;\;\text{and}\;\;|b_{k'}-L|=|a_{n_{k'}}-L|<\varepsilon.$$
The notations may not be the same, but you'll find that we have proven exactly that $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $L$!

Comment: You are very welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon >0$. Since $a_k\to L$ when $k\to \infty $, there is $N$ s.t. $k\geq N$ implies $|a_k-L|<\varepsilon $. In particular if $k\geq N$, then $n_k\geq N$, and thus $$|b_k-L|=|a_{n_k}-L|<\varepsilon .$$

Answer (score 0):

we will just use what you have proven $n_{k} \geq k$.first fix some arbitrary $\epsilon$ then we know that
$$\exists N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N} \,\, \forall n \geq N \,:\, |a_{n} - L| < \epsilon$$

we claim  following

$$\forall k \geq N_{\epsilon} \,:\, |b_{k}-L| = |a_{k} -L|< \epsilon $$

because $|b_{k}-L| = |a_{(n_k)}-L|$ now since $n_{k} \geq k \geq N_{\epsilon}$ we have that $|a_{(n_k)}-L| < \epsilon$

---

It can be summarized as follows

> Every subsequence of convergent sequence converges to same limit

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $a_n\to L$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

Now, note that for any $k\geq N$ we have $n_k\geq k \geq N$ and, since $n_k \geq N$, we also have that $|a_{n_k}-L|<\epsilon$ from the first sentence.

So, for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that for all $k\geq N$ we have $|a_{n_k}-L|<\epsilon$. Hence, $a_{n_k}\to L$ as $k\to\infty$.